# Export and Import Macro & MacroInstructions

Tags: data-loader, servicecloud, data-export, import, macros

Can anyone please share how to export Macro & It's instructions together and import them in another org?  I'm using Salesforce dataloader tool.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There's the following objects to consider - you may not need all of them if you don't use any *conditionals* within your macros (`ExpressionFilter` & `ExpressionFilterCriteria`) or enable/use *macro folders* (`Folder`).

- [Folder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_folder.htm)
- [Macro](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_macro.htm)

  - > Represents a macro, which is a set of instructions that tells the system to perform one or more tasks.
- [MacroInstruction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_macroinstruction.htm)

  - > Represents an instruction in a macro. An instruction can specify the object that the macro interacts with, the context or publisher that the macro works within, the operation or action that the macro performs, and the target of the macro’s actions
- [ExpressionFilter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_expressionfilter.htm)

  - > Represents a logical expression that’s used to control the execution of macro instructions.
- [ExpressionFilterCriteria](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_expressionfiltercriteria.htm)

  - > Represents a condition in an expression that’s used to control the execution of macro instructions.

You can see the data model as such

[image]

You'll have to, unfortunately, export all those and make sure the new Ids for each inserted record is reflected in their lookups when you insert them, one object at a time.

If you're able to set it up - you can leverage [SFDX Data Move Utility (SFDMU)](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility) to make the above much easier. You'd store all the queries in `export.json` and provide source/target orgs and it'll handle the export/import for you.

```json
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "query": "SELECT Id, AccessType, DeveloperName,IsReadonly,Name,Type FROM Folder WHERE Type = 'Macro'",
            "operation": "Upsert",
            "externalId": "Id"
        },
        {
            "query": "SELECT Id, Description, FolderId, Name, OwnerId, StartingContext FROM Macro",
            "operation": "Upsert",
            "externalId": "Id"
        },
        {
            "query": "SELECT Id, MacroId, Name, Operation, SortOrder, Target, Value FROM MacroInstruction",
            "operation": "Upsert",
            "externalId": "Id"
        },
        {
            "query": "SELECT Id, ContextId, FilterConditionLogic, FilterDescription, Name FROM ExpressionFilter",
            "operation": "Upsert",
            "externalId": "Id"
        },
        {
            "query": "SELECT Id, ExpressionFilterId, FilterTarget, FilterTargetValue, Name, Operation, SortOrder FROM ExpressionFilterCriteria",
            "operation": "Upsert",
            "externalId": "Id"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, a simple command would kick off the export from the source org and import into the target org

`sfdx sfdmu:run --sourceusername mySource@local.org --targetusername myTarget@local.org`

---

Otherwise, if you want to understand each step or have to do this manually:

**Export**

- `SELECT Id,AccessType, DeveloperName,IsReadonly,Name,ParentId,Type FROM Folder WHERE Type = 'Macro'`

  - `ParentId` will point to whether this folder is nested - in which case you'll have to insert parent folders first before inserting the nested ones.
- `SELECT Id, Description, FolderId, Name, OwnerId, StartingContext FROM Macro`

  - `FolderId` will point to the related folder the macro is under from above query
- `SELECT Id, MacroId, Name, Operation, SortOrder, Target, Value FROM MacroInstruction`

  - `MacroId` will point to the related `Macro` in the other query
- `SELECT Id, ContextId, FilterConditionLogic, FilterDescription, Name FROM ExpressionFilter`

  - `ContextId` will point to the related `MacroInstruction` in the above query
- `SELECT Id, ExpressionFilterId, FilterTarget, FilterTargetValue, Name, Operation, SortOrder FROM ExpressionFilterCriteria`

  - `ExpressionFilterId` will point to the related `ExpressionFilter` record in the above query

---

**Import**

Now that you have data for all 5 objects. You want to do the following:

- **Insert** parent `Folder` records
- Save mapping of old `Folder` record Ids to newly inserted Ids
- Update remaining `Folder` records' `ParentId` to point to new Id
- **Insert** remaining `Folder` reports (*and repeat as necessary*)
- Save mapping of old `Folder` record Ids to newly inserted Ids
- Update `Macro` `ParentId` to point to new Id
- **Insert** `Macro`
- Save mapping of old `Macro` record Ids to newly inserted Ids
- Update `MacroInstruction` `MacroId` field in csv to point to new Id
- **Insert** `MacroInstruction`
- Save mapping of old `MacroInstruction` record Ids to newly inserted Ids
- Update `ExpressionFilter` `ContextId` field in csv to point to new Id
- **Insert** `ExpressionFilter` records
- Save mapping of old `ExpressionFilter` record Ids to newly inserted Ids
- Update `ExpressionFilterCriteria` `ExpressionFilterId` field in csv to point to newly insert Ids
- **Insert** `ExpressionFilterCriteria` records

---

Comment: +1 great answer; also vendor alternatives to SFDMU like Prodly or Gearset